# Reflection alternative for dynamic loading classes

Tags: magento2, class

I'm currently writing a module that allows wordpress style shortcodes to be used inside the Magento 2 categories, blogs and pages.

I'm at the point where the shortcode class and key => value pairs are taken from the page and are detecting whether the relevant class is available in the plugins' folder.

```
$class = new ReflectionClass( __NAMESPACE__ . "\\Shortcode\\" . $attributes['class'] );
```

As an example I'm loading the class "product" who's code is below

```
class product extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper {
protected $product;
public function __construct( 
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $product
  ){
    $this->product = $product;
  }
  public function execute(){
    $content = "";
    return $content;
  }
}
```

If I pass the arguments into it with

```
$instance = $class->newInstanceArgs( array( $attributes['arguments'] ) );
```

I then get an error that there isn't an instance of \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface being passed as the first argument.

If I don't pass arguments and use a setter method for the parameters, I can't use any of the product methods inside my product class

```
public function execute(){
    $this->product->getById(12874);
    $content = "";
    return $content;
}

"Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getById() on null"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to use reflection, I've injected

```
\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager
```

Into the parent class' constructor, only for loading the relevant sub-classes and methods